# Function returns a corrupted array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arduino

I have read some old questions and tested some ideas, but my issue still exists, so here is what I want:

I need a function that returns a simple array with a fixed size of 181 integer values.

After some tests I have this function:

```cpp
int *Sonar::scan(int *distances) {
    // Scanning
    for (int i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
        // Rotates sonar
        //this->rotate(i);
        // Gets the distance
        //distances[i] = this->getDistance();
        distances[i] = i;
    }
    // Returns
    return distances;
}
```

And call it this way:

```cpp
            // Sonar
            case 's':
                int distances[181];
                *distances = sonar.scan(distances);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
                    Serial.println(String(i) + ": " + String(distances[i]));
                }
                break;
```

But I get this result:

```
0: 1898
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
...
```

The value of index 0 is corrupted all the time. So what mistake do I make?

Comment: `*distances = sonar.scan(distances);` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `scan` returns an `int*`. How can it be assigned to `*distances`?

Comment: Related: Arrays are not pointers

Comment: Yes, maybe thats the mistake. But how to change it?

Comment: You don't need the method to return anything. It changes the elements of the `distances` array that was passed into the function. When it returns the caller can directly use the original `distances` array.

Comment: Changed it to `*distances = sonar.scan(*distances);` and now it works :-)

Comment: If you really feel the need to return something, look into `std::array`. It has the value semantics you're expecting and copy elision will likely  chop the actual copying down to size.

Comment: @kaylum Yes, i know, that i don't need this return. But it's no problem, or is it maybe?

Comment: @Sukombu that is not the correct fix.

Comment: Don't post that as an answer. It'll be sunk with a barrage of downvotes. It's not doing what you think it's doing. I'm not sure it should even compile.

Comment: @user4581301 Hm the std-namespace seems not to work for me, because i need to use the Arduino tools for this project.

Comment: @user4581301 Fine, if it's not the solution then why it works? What is the solution? Only to use `std::array`? i just want a `function` what returns or 'works on' an array or simple field. i don't need dynamic allocation. because a fixed size is fine for my application.

Comment: Does your compiler not complain about pointers being assigned to `int`s?

Comment: @Sukombu The return is not the problem. The problem is that arrays cannot be set to a different value which is what you seem to be intending to do. I mean the array itself and not the elements it contains. Though that's not what you do anyway: `*distances` is the first element of the array. So it makes no sense to set it to `distances` which is what the method returns. It's the same as `*distances = distances;` which should be obviously nonsensical.

Comment: Back to the very first comment.  Figure out what `*distances` is.  Then figure out if you really want to assign something to it.  Knowing that will answer your question.

Comment: Have stopped working :-( So how to solve it?

Comment: Why does this function return any value at all? It takes a pointer to the array it's going to modify and modifies that in place.

Comment: Didn't see the arduino tag. Yeah, most of the C++ library tricks don't work with arduino because it's basically C++ with a C standard library and a few extensions.

Comment: @DrewDormann No, this answers not my question, because `distances = sonar.scan(distances);` doesn't work :-(

Comment: Okay, i just want to work on 181 elements and i have a function what creates this elements and i have another place outside of this function, where need to work with this elements. so how to do it? i have no idea, what to do now. :-(

Comment: Why does it "work"... You're going to hate this one: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). There's a lot of places in C++ where the standard doesn't say what's going to happen if you do it. When you trip over one of these little bombs sometimes you get the behaviour you expect. Sometimes you don't. Sometimes you get it sometimes and not others. UB  <expletive deleted>ing sucks.

Comment: In what way should I edit my question to make it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first element of the array is being overwritten with the pointer to the array when you do:

```
*distances = sonar.scan(distances);
```

That is because you dereference the array with `*distances` giving a reference to the first element. You then assign to that with what you return from the `scan` method (the pointer to the array).

Just doing:

```
sonar.scan(distances);
```

would give the result you expect.

There is no need to return from the method as you are passing the array by a form of reference (a pointer) and that means the array is being changed in place.